# How can I make the second popup appear?

Tags: javascript, button, html, popup

I've made a fiddle from my problem
http://jsfiddle.net/bYMGZ/7/
The first popup displays from pressing the first button but the second popup does not display. Could you help me track down the error?

Thanks

Comment: But for me both the alert message is coming

Comment: Both are displaying just fine for me.

Comment: Same here. Maybe a browser issue?

Comment: Yes, there are 2 alerts coming at both places but only the left button renders a new page. There should be a new page rendering when pressing the button to the right just as a new page displays when the button on the right is pressed that appears just after the alert msg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the chrome developer tools, I see that the sokF div is within the popupSokNamn div. You may have forgotten to close one of the tags somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much. This might be the key to the whole problem. I will follow this answer and report back how it is working.